Is there a way to automatically flush permalinks in Word Press?
I need to save the permalinks on a site a few times daily, and want to know if it's possible to have this done automatically.
The Word Press function to flush permalinks is flush_rewrite_rules(). Is it possible to get this function to run on its own on a timer? Once an hour?
I found this code here, but it does not work, and I do not understand how it would run every hour -
add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly');

function my_activation() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('my_hourly_event')) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event');
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'my_activation');

function do_this_hourly() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}



This is using WP's Cron functionality, you can go read up on that in more detail here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/

"I need to save the permalinks on a site a few times daily" - if you don’t mind me asking, why?

I think I’d handle this outside of WordPress with a system-level cron running wp rewrite flush
